# haproxy limit access to root path for specific ip range, but allow from anywhere for specific subdirectory

Tags: haproxy

I'm using **HA-Proxy** version **1.8.19**

I want to restrict access from external or allow access only for specific IP Range to my website `https://testxy.com/`, but want to allow access from anywhere to subfolder `https://testxy.com/tempDownload/`.

I tried it already with following:

```
http-request deny if { path -i -m beg / } !{ src 10.10.20.0/24 }
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http-request allow if { path_dir -i /tempDownload } { src 0.0.0.0/0 }
http-request allow if { path_dir -i /xy1 } { src 10.10.20.0/24 }
http-request allow if { path_dir -i /xy2 } { src 10.10.20.0/24 }
http-request deny if { path_dir -i -m beg / } !{ src 10.10.20.0/24 }
```

This solved my problem (if anyone else has the same question)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the exact match instead of `beg` [path](http://git.haproxy.org/?p=haproxy-2.4.git;a=blob;f=doc/configuration.txt;h=31f84933847585e669c25449cf71a6949a5a61fa;hb=HEAD#l19457)

The `-i` is here also useless as there is no lower- or upper-case version of `/` [ACL Flags](http://git.haproxy.org/?p=haproxy-2.4.git;a=blob;f=doc/configuration.txt;h=31f84933847585e669c25449cf71a6949a5a61fa;hb=HEAD#l15451)

```
http-request deny if { path / } !{ src 10.10.20.0/24 }
```

Comment: ok thank you for this hint, but how can i allow only the /tempDownload/ path for anyone else?